# Toolbar doesn't appear when open app but if i turn device to landscape it appears

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, react-native

The toolbar for navigate to marker and open in google maps using [airbnb/react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) have a strange behaviour on startup. It appears after a long time navigating the app or if i turn the device to landscape. But when i open the app the toolbar doesn't appear. There is a event or some property that i missed?

[image]

```
render() {
    const { region, markers,air } = this.state;

    return (

    <MapView
      style={Styles.map}
      initialRegion={region}
      loadingEnabled={true}
      toolbarEnabled={true}
      loadingIndicatorColor={"#666666"}
      loadingBackgroundColor={"#eeeeee"}
    >
      {this.state.air.map(marker => (
        <MapView.Marker
          key={marker.created_at}
          coordinate={{
            latitude: parseFloat(marker.latitude),
            longitude: parseFloat(marker.longitude),
          }}
          pinColor='#38b57f'
          title={marker.artist.name}
          description={marker.adress}
          onCalloutPress={this._gotoObraView.bind(this, {marker: marker})}
        />
      ))}
    </MapView>
    );
}
```

[i openned a issue as well in github project page](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/610)

Comment: share your code

Comment: @PradeepGupta i added the render method where i turn to true the toolbar. The toolbar works but not when the app opens only after a few moments or if i rotate the device which is strange.

Answer (score 1):

To go around it, I made a little hack. I realized that if you update the size of the screen at least once, the bar shows.
 Then initially I set a style property 'bottom' to 1 (users will not notice this) and make that property part of the component's state.

Then the first time the user select one marker, we set the property 'bottom' of the state to 0, forcing to render the component again, and re dimension the map, and Voila!!! your bar will be shown.

I hope it helps ;-)

Here is the code for it:

```
class Locations extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
              bottom: 1 
               }
    }

       toolbarHack = () => {
          if(this.state.bottom === 1){
            this.setState({
              bottom: 0
            })
          } 
        }

    render() { 

      return (
        <View style ={styles.container}>
          <MapView
            style={ [styles.map, { bottom:this.state.bottom}] }
            region={region} 
            toolbarEnabled={true} >

            {
              this.props.markers.map((marker) =>
               (<MapView.Marker
                  coordinate={{longitude: marker.longitude, latitude: marker.latitude}}
                  key={marker.id} 
                   onPress={() => this.toolbarHack()}
                  />
                  ))
                  }
          </MapView>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```